# Not able to save data as arrays to then save as CSV

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv

I'm trying to save the data from stocks I'm gathering from an API using this line of code `await yahooStockAPI.getHistoricalPrices(startDate, endDate, symbol, '1d');` and save it as an array named `newData`, however, I keep getting an empty array. If I do `console.log(newData);` I can see the ouput which is something like this (for each symbol that I have defined in the code)...

```
{
  error: false,
  currency: 'USD',
  response: [
    {
      date: 1627047000,
      open: 147.5500030517578,
      high: 148.72000122070312,
      low: 146.9199981689453,
      close: 148.55999755859375,
      volume: 71447400,
      adjclose: 148.33775329589844
    },
    {
      date: 1626960600,
      open: 145.94000244140625,
      high: 148.1999969482422,
      low: 145.80999755859375,
      close: 146.8000030517578,
      volume: 77338200,
      adjclose: 146.58038330078125
    },...
```

... however, the CSV file that has been saved in the directory I've set is empty and I get an error `The input to objects-to-csv must be an array of objects` . I want to put the output above as an array of objects `newData` to then turn it into a CSV file using a NPM package. Essentially, the array would be something like this (which is the same order as `const symbol`:

```
const newData = [
    {date: '...', open: open price for apple, high: highest price for amazon, low:..., etc},
    {date: '...', open: open price for amazon, high: highest price for google, low:..., etc},
];
```

I don't mind if each object inside of the array doesn't have the ticker for each stock since I have the `const symbol` which is ordered

This is the code:

```
const yahooStockAPI  = require('yahoo-stock-api');
const ObjectsToCsv = require('objects-to-csv');

const symbol = ['AAPL','AMZN','GOOGL']
symbol.forEach(main);

let newData = []; 

async function main(symbol) {
  const startDate = new Date('01/01/2018');
  const endDate = new Date('08/01/2021');
  newData = await yahooStockAPI.getHistoricalPrices(startDate, endDate, symbol, '1d');

  //console.log(newData);

  (async () => {
    const csv = new ObjectsToCsv(newData);
    await csv.toDisk('C:/Users/Rafael Oliveira/Desktop/teste/test2.csv');
  })();

};
main();
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ObjectsToCsv` package is expecting an array of objects to be passed to it, however from the logged data that you have shared, `newData` is an object. The exact data you are looking for can be accessed by `newData.response`. So the following line of code should work:

> const csv = new ObjectsToCsv(newData.response);

Comment: Thank you so much! I was now able to get the data for "AAPL", but I don't seem to find the rest of the data (for amazon and google) in the CSV file. I'm already doing the `symbol.forEach(main)`, so it should also save the data in the same CSV file, correct?

Comment: @Rafael that's a different issue-- you're probably overwriting your file.  Can I suggest you open a new question since it's not the original problem?